# WordPress - Overlay a white block containing text, on the left of a photo

Tags: wordpress, position, z-index, block, superimpose

For the needs of an internship project in WordPress, I decided to slightly superimpose a white block containing text, on the left of a photo.

These two elements are in a container.

This is [my-figma-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrfcG.jpg).

I already tried to play with the z-index and the position, only it works on the text contained in the block and not on the block itself...

I also failed to paste the image on the right edge of the screen without the white block being stuck to the left edge.

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same with negative padding and z-index, remember to apply a lower z-index to the second column and not to the general horizontal block.

Comment: I tested it and it works! Thank you!